# Decompress BZ2 with php (__HALT_COMPILER(); not found)

Tags: php

I try to unzip bz2 file with a php script but i have this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: internal
>   corruption of phar
>   "/Users/apple/projects/asystem/database/dump/xxxx.sql.bz2"
>   (__HALT_COMPILER(); not found) in
>   /Users/apple/projects/asystem/database/dump/dump_auctions.php:33 Stack
>   trace:
>   0 /Users/apple/projects/asystem/database/dump/dump_auctions.php(33): PharData->__construct('auct_auctions_x...')
>   1 {main}   thrown in /Users/apple/projects/asystem/database/dump/dump_auctions.php on line
>   33

What i'm trying to achieve is: Download file from FTP, decompress and import in to database. But im stuck on decompressing **bz2**

This is my code:

```
    <?php

    // Download Auctions dump

    // define some variables
    $local_file = "xxxx.sql.bz2";
    $server_file = "xxxx.sql.bz2";

    //-- Connection Settings
    $ftp_server = "xxxxx.xxxxx.com"; // Address of FTP server.
    $ftp_user_name = "xxxxxx_user"; // Username
    $ftp_user_pass = "xxxxx"; // Password


    // set up basic connection
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

    // login with username and password
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

    // try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
    if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
    } else {
        echo "There was a problem\n";
    }

    // close the connection
    ftp_close($conn_id);

    // unzip file
    $p = new PharData('xxxx.sql.bz2');
    $p->decompress(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://devzone.zend.com/1307/working-with-rar-lzf-and-bz2-compression-formats-in-php/).

Just used this code:

```
// set input and output files
$out = 'xxxx.sql';
$in = 'xxxx.sql.bz2';

// decompress file using BZIP2
if (file_exists($in)) {
    $data = '';
    $bz = bzopen($in, 'r') or die('ERROR: Cannot open input file!');
    while (!feof($bz)) {
        $data .= bzread($bz, 4096) or die('ERROR: Cannot read from input file');;
    }
    bzclose($bz);
    file_put_contents($out, $data) or die('ERROR: Cannot write to output file!');
    echo 'Decompression complete.';
}
```